# My controller get null value when i get list by id

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

why my controller gets the null value for Address, Phone, UserName, Email?

When i debug, Payment2 POST has received id from view and has a value.

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Payment2(int id)
{
    model md = new model();
    var pm = new paymentmodel();
    var cart = Session[CartSession];
    if (cart != null)
    {
        md.v1 = (List<CartItemModel>)cart;
    }
    md.v2 = pm.userdetails(id);
    return View(md);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Payment2(int id, User c)
{
    var cart = (List<CartItemModel>)Session[CartSession];
    foreach (var item in cart)
    {
        if (item.quantity > item.Product.suspended)
        {
            return Redirect("/loi-so-luong");
        }
    }
    var oder = new HoaDon();
    oder.Date = DateTime.Now;
    oder.Address = c.Address;
    oder.Phone = c.Phone;
    oder.TenNguoiNhan = c.UserName;
    oder.E_mail = c.Email; 
    }
    return Redirect("/hoan-thanh");
}
```

NULL with `Address`, `Phone`, `UserName`, `Email`

My model.cs:

```
public class model
{

    public List<CartItemModel> v1 { set; get; }

    public List<get_customer_Result> v2 { set; get; }
}
```

My paymentmodel:

```
public class paymentmodel
{
    KINHDOANHVLXDEntities ke = new KINHDOANHVLXDEntities();
    public List<get_customer_Result> userdetails(int id)
       {
          var ln = ke.get_customer(id);

          return ln.ToList();
        }
}
```

My index view:

```
@model List<thuctaplan2.Models.CartItemModel>
@using thuctaplan2.Common
  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
     var session = (UserLogin)Session[CommonConstants.USER_SESSION];
   }

  <a href="@Url.Action("Payment2", new { id = session.id_NguoiDung})" class="btn">Thanh Toán</a>
```

My Payment2 View:

```
@model thuctaplan2.Models.model
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Thanh Toán";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Payment2", "Cart", FormMethod.Post))
    {
            foreach (var item in Model.v2)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <label>@item.UserName</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                   <label>@item.Phone</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <label>@item.Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>E-mail</label>
                   <label>@item.Email</label>
                </div>
            }
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
        }
```

Comment: Your `Payment2` View does not have any editable form controls (there is nothing to submit). What are you trying to do here?

Comment: this only is a part of my view, i think i have problem with this. What i focus is why value null.

Comment: please help me !!! :(

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here based on your code is that when you render your view, all your controls inside your Form is empty or with no value, in short, null. Why? Because you only render label html elements inside your Form.

In order to have a value, add a textbox like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

So that when you submit your Form, your `User` model properties like `UserName` will have a value. If this are all labels only, no value will be passed to your controller.